# Keeping the delimiter in preg_split in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am trying to split a text file into pieces based on a specific delimiter.

A snippet of the text file

```
    1_1_ABA-BUL
Sat           Tjedan(i)   Datum            Učiona     Predavač(i)        Kolegij             Način   Grupa
Ponedjeljak
08:00-10:00   1 - 17      5.10    - 25.1   DV 12      ŠTAMPALIJA ALKA    POSLOVNI NJEMAČKI   P       1_1_ABA-BUL, 1_2_BULJ-GAB, 1_3_GAC-JUK,
                                                                         JEZIK I                     1_4_JUL-LOR, 1_5_LOS-MOR
10:00-12:00   1 - 17      5.10    - 25.1   SPORTSKA   HERCEG ROMINA      TJELESNA I          S       1_1_2_BES-BUL
                                                                         ZDRAVSTVENA
                                                                         KULTURA I
12:00-14:00   1 - 17      5.10    - 25.1   DV 26      VARGA MLADEN       INFORMATIKA         P       1_1_ABA-BUL
Utorak
08:00-10:00   1 - 17      6.10    - 26.1   DV 12      ŠTAMPALIJA ALKA    POSLOVNI NJEMAČKI   S       1_1_ABA-BUL, 1_2_BULJ-GAB, 1_3_GAC-JUK,
                                                                         JEZIK I                     1_4_JUL-LOR, 1_5_LOS-MOR
08:00-10:00   1 - 17      6.10    - 26.1   DV 20      SLADOLJEV AGEJEV   POSLOVNI ENGLESKI   P       1_1_ABA-BUL
                                                      TAMARA             JEZIK I
12:00-14:00   1 - 17      6.10    - 26.1   DV 40      ZOROJA JOVANA      INFORMATIKA         S       1_1_1_ABA-BER
12:00-14:00   1 - 17      6.10    - 26.1   DV 18      SLADOLJEV AGEJEV   POSLOVNI ENGLESKI   S       1_1_2_BES-BUL
                                                      TAMARA             JEZIK I
Srijeda
08:00-11:00   1 - 17      7.10    - 27.1   DV 01      PULJIĆ KRUNOSLAV   MATEMATIKA          P       1_1_ABA-BUL
11:00-14:00   1 - 17      7.10    - 27.1   DV 01      KRPAN MIRA         OSNOVE EKONOMIJE    P       1_1_ABA-BUL
14:00-16:00   1 - 17      7.10    - 27.1   DV 11      SLADOLJEV AGEJEV   POSLOVNI ENGLESKI   S       1_1_1_ABA-BER
                                                      TAMARA             JEZIK I
Četvrtak
11:00-14:00   1 - 17      8.10    - 28.1   DV 04      SLIŠKOVIĆ MARINA   MATEMATIKA          S       1_1_1_ABA-BER
Petak
09:00-12:00   1 - 17      9.10    - 29.1   DV 20      KRPAN MIRA         OSNOVE EKONOMIJE    S       1_1_2_BES-BUL
10:00-12:00   1 - 17      9.10    - 29.1   SPORTSKA   HERCEG ROMINA      TJELESNA I          S       1_1_1_ABA-BER
ZDRAVSTVENA
KULTURA I

12:00-15:00   1 - 17   9.10   - 29.1   DV 09   KRPAN MIRA         OSNOVE EKONOMIJE   S   1_1_1_ABA-BER
13:00-16:00   1 - 17   9.10   - 29.1   DV 01   SLIŠKOVIĆ MARINA   MATEMATIKA         S   1_1_2_BES-BUL
16:00-18:00   1 - 17   9.10   - 29.1   DV 40   AVDIĆ AMMAR,       INFORMATIKA        S   1_1_2_BES-BUL
VANJSKI INF

1_2_BULJ-GAB
Sat            Tjedan(i)   Datum            Učiona     Predavač(i)          Kolegij             Način   Grupa
Ponedjeljak
08:00-10:00    1 - 17      5.10    - 25.1   DV 12      ŠTAMPALIJA ALKA      POSLOVNI NJEMAČKI   P       1_1_ABA-BUL, 1_2_BULJ-GAB, 1_3_GAC-JUK,
                                                                            JEZIK I                     1_4_JUL-LOR, 1_5_LOS-MOR
10:00-13:00    1 - 17      5.10    - 25.1   DV 16      ŠEGO BOŠKO           MATEMATIKA          P       1_2_BULJ-GAB
14:00-16:00    1 - 17      5.10    - 25.1   DV 17      LEKAJ LUBINA BORKA   POSLOVNI ENGLESKI   P       1_2_BULJ-GAB
                                                                            JEZIK I
Utorak
08:00-10:00    1 - 17      6.10    - 26.1   DV 12      ŠTAMPALIJA ALKA      POSLOVNI NJEMAČKI   S       1_1_ABA-BUL, 1_2_BULJ-GAB, 1_3_GAC-JUK,
                                                                            JEZIK I                     1_4_JUL-LOR, 1_5_LOS-MOR
10:00-12:00    1 - 17      6.10    - 26.1   DV 01      PEJIĆ BACH MIRJANA   INFORMATIKA         P       1_2_BULJ-GAB
15:00-18:00    1 - 17      6.10    - 26.1   DV 11      HERCEG TOMISLAV      OSNOVE EKONOMIJE    P       1_2_BULJ-GAB
Srijeda
08:00-10:00    1 - 17      7.10    - 27.1   DV 42      MILANOVIĆ GLAVAN     INFORMATIKA         S       1_2_1_BULJ-DAJ
LJUBICA
10:00-12:00    1 - 17      7.10    - 27.1   DV 42      MILANOVIĆ GLAVAN     INFORMATIKA         S       1_2_2_DAK-GAB
                                                       LJUBICA
10:00-12:00    1 - 17      7.10    - 27.1   SPORTSKA   HERCEG ROMINA        TJELESNA I          S       1_2_1_BULJ-DAJ
                                                                            ZDRAVSTVENA
                                                                            KULTURA I
15:00-18:00    1 - 17      7.10    - 27.1   DV 23      HERCEG TOMISLAV      OSNOVE EKONOMIJE    S       1_2_1_BULJ-DAJ
18:00-21:00    1 - 17      7.10    - 27.1   DV 23      HERCEG TOMISLAV      OSNOVE EKONOMIJE    S       1_2_2_DAK-GAB
Četvrtak
Petak
10:00-12:00    1 - 17      9.10    - 29.1   SPORTSKA   HERCEG ROMINA        TJELESNA I          S       1_2_2_DAK-GAB
                                                                            ZDRAVSTVENA
                                                                            KULTURA I
11:00-14:00    1 - 17      9.10    - 29.1   DV 19      ŠKRINJARIĆ TIHANA    MATEMATIKA          S       1_2_1_BULJ-DAJ

12:00-14:00   1 - 17   9.10   - 29.1   DV 16   LEKAJ LUBINA BORKA   POSLOVNI ENGLESKI   S   1_2_2_DAK-GAB
                                                                    JEZIK I
14:00-17:00   1 - 17   9.10   - 29.1   DV 02   ŠKRINJARIĆ TIHANA    MATEMATIKA          S   1_2_2_DAK-GAB
14:00-16:00   1 - 17   9.10   - 29.1   DV 10   LEKAJ LUBINA BORKA   POSLOVNI ENGLESKI   S   1_2_1_BULJ-DAJ
JEZIK I
```

I am splitting the string at the 1_1_ABA-BUL line and the other lines of the same format (above the "Sat" string).

This is my preg_split line

```
$grupe = preg_split("/((.*?)\nSat)/", $source, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY |  PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

The following preg_split line doesn't keep the delimiter (1_1_ABA-BUL etc.). If I change it to

```
  $grupe = preg_split("/((.*?)\nSat)/", $source, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY |  PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

The resulting arrays are not correct (I get a corrupt result).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way you use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) seems to work but in fact it doesn't.

It's third argument (`$limit`) is the number of pieces to return. It happened that the texts you used were not long enough and the number of pieces was smaller than or equal to 3 (the value of `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`).

This is how you can make it work:

```
$grupe = preg_split('/(.*?)\n(?=Sat)/', $source, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

This is a (truncated) listing of `print_r($grupe)`:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>     1_1_ABA-BUL
    [1] => Sat           Tjedan(i)   Datum            Učiona     Predavač(i)        Kolegij             Način   Grupa
Ponedjeljak
08:00-10:00   1 - 17      5.10    - 25.1   DV 12      ŠTAMPALIJA ALKA    POSLOVNI NJEMAČKI   P       1_1_ABA-BUL, 1_2_BULJ-GAB, 1_3_GAC-JUK,
                                                                         JEZIK I                     1_4_JUL-LOR, 1_5_LOS-MOR
...
16:00-18:00   1 - 17   9.10   - 29.1   DV 40   AVDIĆ AMMAR,       INFORMATIKA        S   1_1_2_BES-BUL
VANJSKI INF


    [2] => 1_2_BULJ-GAB
    [3] => Sat            Tjedan(i)   Datum            Učiona     Predavač(i)          Kolegij             Način   Grupa
Ponedjeljak
08:00-10:00    1 - 17      5.10    - 25.1   DV 12      ŠTAMPALIJA ALKA      POSLOVNI NJEMAČKI   P       1_1_ABA-BUL, 1_2_BULJ-GAB, 1_3_GAC-JUK,
...
14:00-16:00   1 - 17   9.10   - 29.1   DV 10   LEKAJ LUBINA BORKA   POSLOVNI ENGLESKI   S   1_2_1_BULJ-DAJ
JEZIK I

)
```

**How it works:**

The important change of the regular expression is the [assertion](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) `(?=Sat)`. It says the previous part of the regex (`(.*?)\n`) matches a part of the string only if that part of the string is followed by `Sat`. The assertion only checks the next characters from the input string but doesn't consume them. The `Sat` part does not become a part of the delimiter.

The rest is unchanged. The flag `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` makes `preg_split()` return the captured parts of the regex delimiter as individual pieces of the output. Find them above at offsets `0` and `2`. The `Sat` substring, being just an assertion is not part of the delimiter but it is returned in the next piece (where it belongs).

Comment: Is there any way to make this work where the delimiter isn't pulled off into it's own array value? I would have thought that if you're trying to keep the delimiter it would stay in the actual text clumps.